# Wagtail: How to render the blocks dynamically on Admin panel?

Tags: wagtail

In wagtail, I need to make a Struct/Stream Block
There is a dropdown on the top of the block(Image/Video)
If editor choose Image, VideoChooserBlock should be hidden.
And if editor choose Video, ImageChooserBlock should be hidden.

```
class MyBlock(StruckBlock):
   category = ChoiceBlock(choices=(("image", "image"),("video", "video")))
   image = ImageChooserBlock()
   video = videoChooserBlock()
```

Here, editor should be able to choose only image or video depending on category.
Any help is appriciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may find it useful to review the code of [wagtail-link-block](https://github.com/developersociety/wagtail-link-block) which does something similar.

Main files to focus on:

- [blocks.py](https://github.com/developersociety/wagtail-link-block/blob/0.1.3/wagtail_link_block/blocks.py#L47-L70) for displaying fields conditionally based on a ChoiceBlock
- [static/link_block/link_block.js](https://github.com/developersociety/wagtail-link-block/blob/0.1.3/wagtail_link_block/static/link_block/link_block.js) and [static/link_block/link_block.css](https://github.com/developersociety/wagtail-link-block/blob/0.1.3/wagtail_link_block/static/link_block/link_block.css) to handle the DOM manipulation and styling with JavaScript and CSS
- [wagtail_hooks.py](https://github.com/developersociety/wagtail-link-block/blob/0.1.3/wagtail_link_block/wagtail_hooks.py#L7-L14) to insert JS and CSS